# Change css of element (same element for different parents)

Tags: html, css

I would like to change style for all my anchor elements. i want them to be same, disregarded of their parent.

so just to write something like this:

```
a { color: red }
```

and to apply this to all elements.

This is because I'm changing some theme, and I can't do it like this, because for some classes or elements, anchor tags are styled differently, and I'm wondering if I can change it somehow.
The other way is to find all these style rules, and to change it there (if there is no simpler solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override CSS styling with your own using `!important`. Here's a good [tutorial](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).

In your case, if you're looking to override the color of links, you can do something like this:

```
a { 
color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: That will work! I'll mark your question as best, as soon as stackoverflow lets me :) thanks